# Symetric product of smooth toric variety

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Hi everybody  i have a doubt..the n-symetric power of an smooth toric variety X is also a smooth toric variety ?..probably its not true in general case but someone can help me for find the conditions over this statement is true..i am trying to find a fan associated to symetric power using the fan associated to X...or maybe the question is more general..if G is finite group and acting on smooth toric variety then the quotient X\G (suppose that its well defined) is a smooth toric variety ?

thank you and please help me

Comment: Forgetting for a moment about "toric", in general a finite quotient of a smooth variety need not be smooth, and in particular a symmetric product of a smooth variety of dimension more than 1 will not be smooth.

Comment: thank u ..yes i know the symetric is not smooth but if i take the symetric product of the smooth projective curve then it wil be smooth (kempf proof this)...then i have to reformolize my question ...the symetric product of a toric variety is also a toric variety ?...its posible consider a smooth projective curve as smooth toriv variety ? or its wrong by the fact the does not contain an algebraic torus ?